# Getting a Method object representing the origin of an Exception

Tags: java, reflection, exception

Is it possible in Java, to get a Method object representing the method in which an exception was thrown provided nothing but said exception?

Given the example:

```
public class Test {

    protected void toFail() throws Exception {
        throw new Exception();
    }

    protected void toFail(String someparameter) throws Exception {
        throw new Exception();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            new Test().toFail("");
        }catch(Exception ex){
            //Clever code here
        }
    }

}
```

What clever code would allow me to get a Method object representing the toFail(String) method? Assuming its even possible :)

Clarification:
I need to uniquely identify the method that caused the exception, and i need to be able to create a reflection Method object from it. When i say uniquely i mean that i need to take the possibility of overloaded methods into account.

Comment: You want to find out which method threw the exception?

Comment: Yes, specifically i would like to be able to identify the method between several overloaded variants.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get the name of the class and method it was thrown from like this:

```
StackTraceElement ste = exception.getStackTrace()[0];

String className = ste.getClassName();
String methodName = ste.getMethodName();
```

But you can't get the `Method` object because the `StackTraceElement` does not record *which* of the methods with the same name.

You can get the *possible* `Method` objects (*possible* as with *matching* name) like this:

```
StackTraceElement ste = exception.getStackTrace()[0];

Class<?> c = Class.forName(ste.getClassName());
String mname = ste.getMethodName();

// NOTE:
// Exceptions thrown in constructors have a method name of "<init>"
// Exceptions thrown in static initialization blocks have a method name of
//    "<cinit>"

if ("<init>".equals(mname)) {
    // Constructors are the possible "methods", all of these:
    c.getConstructors();
} else if ("<cinit>".equals(mname)) {
    System.out.println("Thrown in a static initialization block!");
} else {
    // Thrown from a method:
    for (Method m : c.getMethods()) {
        if (m.getName().equals(mname)) {
            System.out.println("Possible method: " + m);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: But there is no way to identify parameterized methods?

Comment: Nope. Not via standard library. Except if you only have one method with the specified name, you'll know for sure it's that.

Comment: Can you trust line numbers from the stack trace element? And can that somehow be used to uniquely identify the method?

Comment: I've thought about it but line numbers only available in class files and are not exposed via the API (e.g. reflection), and there is no guarantee they are even present in class files (only if compiled with debugging info). Btw line number will only available in the `StackTraceElement` too if it is present in the class file.

Comment: Ok thanks. I guess that's an accepted ansver. And a +1 for the 3-4 edits i saw you make as the comments ticked in:)

Answer (score 0):

Use `StackTrace()` for this.

```
public class Test {

    protected void toFail(String someparameter) throws Exception {
        throw new Exception();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            new Test().toFail("");
        }catch(Exception ex){
            StackTraceElement[] stl = ex.getStackTrace();
            System.out.println(stl[0].getMethodName());
       }
    }
}
```