# How to Manage same Exceptions throwns from @Controller and @RestController?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

In my Spring MVC application, I am using both `@Controller` and `@RestController` components to handle different parts of the application logic. I've set up global exception handling using `@ControllerAdvice` and `@RestControllerAdvice` classes, which works well for handling exceptions thrown from both controllers and rest controllers.

However, I'm facing a scenario where I'm throwing the **same custom exception** from both `@Controller` and `@RestController`. My goal is to differentiate the exception handling behavior based on whether the exception is thrown from a regular `@Controller` or a `@RestController`.

Is there an established approach in Spring MVC to automatically achieve this distinction, or is it necessary to define separate exceptions for both @Controller and @RestController logics.

Your insights and guidance on this matter would be highly appreciated. Thank you for considering my query.

Comment: You can add a source property to your exceptions if you wish. Use that property to decide on the logic you wish to invoke in your handler.

Comment: Thanks Paul for your suggestion,  But I'm currently utilizing a same service method for both REST API endpoints and MVC controllers. This shared service method triggers a common exception in both scenarios. However, I'm seeking guidance on the implementation of a 'source' property in this context, as I'm unsure about the best approach to incorporate it effectively

Answer (score 0):

If you look at [Getting a Method object representing the origin of an Exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25303232/getting-a-method-object-representing-the-origin-of-an-exception), you can get the classname and the method name from the exception when is is caught.

Comment: I think everyone needs to adhere to the spirit of SO. In other words, if you don't have enough reputation to post a comment, don't post a comment as an answer. And by the looks of your "answer" it seems you think that the question is actually a duplicate which means it should be flagged as such. Do you not see the _Close_ or _Flag_ links below the question?

Comment: Hi Abra and @forward, The suggested solution doesn't fit my needs, and this isn't a duplicate inquiry. My challenge arises from using the same service method for both REST API and regular web API requests, making the method name approach ineffective.

I'm seeking insights on whether Spring MVC offers a way to distinguish exception handling between @ Controller and @ RestController, without resorting to separate service methods. While service duplication works, it adds code redundancy without logic changes.

Comment: True, @SafvanP. I was merely giving the merit to somebody that had indicated how to get the origin of an exception being thrown. It is not the best way, as it couples the thrower of the exception with the catching. On the other hand, you're right, I don't think Spring has something to distinguish between the two types of services regarding the advice receiving the exception.